# Python: Different Values of Cosine when converting from deg to rads

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that solves a mathematical function and evaluates a value of a function with the provided x value.
The problem that arose while working in python was when I try to put trig functions first I need to convert degrees to radians. Then using the math module I can evaluate the value of sin or cos. But it seems that when converting from deg to rads the cosine or sine values don't match up for small values.

```
import math
def solveTrigFn(x):
   x_rads = math.radians(x)
   return math.cos(x_rads)
```

Values come differently when converting from deg to rads. Is there a way to calculate trig values in the deg system? and not convert to rads.
I was using a value of 0.6. I even used the google calculator also their the values were different.

Comment: Look up "floating point error".

Comment: `math.cos(math.radians(0.6))` produces the correct result. ie `0.9999451693655121`. In the calculator `cos(0.6) = 0.9999451694`. Note that the two are equivalent

Comment: Google calculator is working on radians. Click on the `Deg` button to work on degrees

Comment: @ScottHunter. Sure I will look it up. I have made a workaround trying to solve this using Taylors polynomial. But the complexity is O(n). Can you suggest any good algorithm to implement Taylor's theorem and approximate the values of trig functions in terms of degrees?

Comment: @Onyambu Google calculator is giving 0.82533561491 on Deg when calculator cos(0.6)

Comment: No. That is calculated on radians. THE default of google calculator is radians: check that versus `math.cos(0.6)`

Comment: Please google how to use radians on google calculator. The result is `0.99994516936` not what you posted